# I have a PDF form where I want to be able to display the date the form was saved

Tags: forms, date, pdf

I have a form that I use daily as a transmittal for when I send items out. I would like once I save the form, the date is displayed. I know how to use the current date format, but this will change the next time I open the saved document, and I want to be able to see the last time it was saved, and not the current date.

Comment: What have you tried?  Try and flesh out your problem a bit more, and code always helps

Answer (score 0):

This works only with Acrobat-JavaScript enabled viewers:

1. Create a text field where you want to have the last save date
2. Add the following script in the WillSave event (in Acrobat XI, it is in the JavaScript Tools --> Document Actions --> Will Save dialog):

   var now = new Date ;

   this.getField("mySaveDate").value = util.printd("yyyy/mmm/dd HH:MM", now) ;

and that should do it.